# ICO: circulating supply vs total supply

Tags: ico

After an ICO, the circulating supply (like you can see on https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bancor/) is what was sold in crowdsale?

I assume founder, reserve, bounty tokens are not included in the circulating supply?
Once a founder sells his tokens are they then added to the circulating supply?

Related to this are those founder & reserve tokens also created during ICO or afterwards when they decide to use them?

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% on the technical definitions of **Circulating Supply vs Total Supply,** but I would believe that any tokens that are NOT trade-able *(for example restricted with a time lock),* would add to the overall total but not the circulating supply.

---

Many ICOs will often reserve approx 30% from the total token supply for their development team's compensation. However, to instill trust in the community, they will often program a time delay *(eg. 1-year)* before those tokens are accessible and can then be added to the circulating supply value, regardless of IF/WHEN they decide to sell them.

---

Unless the ICO's contract contains a **token minting/creating** function, then yes, all tokens `(_totalSupply)` is created at the time of the ICO.